# How to make the buttons in one column using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
 "columns": [
            { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Code", "name": "Code", "autoWidth": true },
            { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
            {
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-group" href="/Grades/' + full.Id + '">Details</a>'; },
            },
            {
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-group" href="/Grades/' + full.Id + '/Edit/">Edit</a>'; },
            },
            {
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) { return '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-group" href="/Grades/' + full.Id + '/Delete/">Delete</a>'; }
            }
        ]
```

Currently i'm using the code above and the view is like in the image. **[Any suggestions !!!]**

**[Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnvE9.png)]**

Answer (score 0):

Just return them in one column like

```
"columns": [
        { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "Code", "name": "Code", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "Name", "name": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
        {
            "orderable": false,
            "searchable": false,
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-group" href="/Grades/' + full.Id + '">Details</a>'
                    + '<a class="btn btn-secondary btn-group" href="/Grades/' + full.Id + '/Edit/">Edit</a>'
                    +'<a class="btn btn-danger btn-group" href="/Grades/' + full.Id + '/Delete/">Delete</a>' ;
            }
        }
]
```

Comment: This is perfect. the (+) needed to break the lines. Thank you so much

Comment: @RomeoJ Great,could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  if you have resolved the problem?

Comment: @ Xing Zou , Then only i can get a confirmation, that the code is working properly. anyway thank you.